# Always get empty response by using ResponseTransformer in wiremock

Tags: java, wiremock

I am having a problem using Wiremock. I need to obtain one field from the request body and show it in the Response.

As I understood I need to extend Response Transformer class and then use this transfomer in stubFor method. But when I trying it out I always get empty response. Also I am not sure how to get only one field from the request body since there is only `getBodyAsString()` method.

My request looks like this

```
{
    "command":"doThis",
    "id":"asfksdjdskj85495848"
}
```

And here is my code just to return all request body in response

```
@Override
public ResponseDefinition transform(Request request, ResponseDefinition responseDefinition, FileSource fileSource, Parameters parameters) {
    return new ResponseDefinitionBuilder()
            .like(responseDefinition)
            .but()
            .withBody(request.getBodyAsString())
            .build();
}


@Override
public boolean applyGlobally() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    return "idTransformer";
}

...
stubFor(post(urlEqualTo("/commands"))
            .withHeader("token", matching(".*"))
            .willReturn(aResponse()
                    .withStatus(200)
                    .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .withTransformers("idTransformer")));
```

In the logs I see this

Matched response definition:

```
{
  "status" : 200,
  "transformers" : [ "idTransformer" ]
}
```

But the response is always empty. Could you please advise what i am doing wrong and how to get only one field `"id"` from the request body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found mistake in my code. I used wrong place for .extension. Here is the correct code

```
public class myMock {

 private static WireMockServer wireMockServer;


 public static void main(String args[]){

    wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(WireMockConfiguration.
            options().notifier(new 
ConsoleNotifier(true)).extensions(IdTransformer.class));

stubFor(post(urlEqualTo("/api/commands/vehicles/FAKEBMWVEHICLE001"))
            .willReturn(aResponse()
                    .withTransformers("idTransformer")
                  ));
}
```